# Convergences of particular subsequence imply convergence of sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If subsequence ${x_{kn}}$ are convergent for every $k\ge2$. Then the sequence ${x_n}$ is convergent?
My approach:
I tried to prove it by things available in net. I am new to handle subsequence concept.

Comment: You probably want to say that the sequences $x_{kn}$ are convergent *to the same limit* right?

Comment: No sir, limit may vary according to subsequence. Didn't mention to converge to the same limit.

Comment: If the limit varies according to the subsequence,the sequente itself is not convergent... A sequence converges if and only if all subsequences converge to the same limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the same limit for $x_{kn}$ and $x_{ln}$ by considering $x_{kln}$ I believe, but I still think that the sequence may diverge. For example $x_n=1$ if $n$ prime, otherwise $x_n=0$.

Comment: I was not able to think this counter ex. Thanks